# How to create batch file which installs and runs file

Tags: batch-file

Hi I have a file on my computer, say fileA. I want to create a batch file to send to my friend. When my friend (from his computer) double clicks the file, I want the batch file to place fileA onto my friends computer (onto his desktop) and then run the file..

Can anyone help me do this? Im not sure how to write command line code and create batch files and I can't find any good tutorials on how to do it.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do this is to upload fileA to a FTP server (better yet, host the FTP server yourself). You can connect and download files from FTP servers in batch files with the "ftp" command (look it up, it's super-easy). After the download was finished you can execute it with "start \fileA".
Good luck.

Comment: hm okay thanks, I managed to get fileA onto a shard drive which my friend is able to access from his computer.. I'm guessing I use the get command. My friend can access files from \\folder\shared, so get \\folder\shared\fileA.. Would that get the file? Where would it place the file which it gets?

Answer (score 1):

I do something similar to what you are asking for, using WGet, [in this script I wrote here](https://github.com/djangofan/WebDriverTestingTemplate/blob/master/startWebDriverGridHub.bat).

```
SET JAR=selenium-server-standalone-2.31.0.jar
SET "WGET=C:\Program Files (x86)\GnuWin32\bin\wget.exe"
IF EXIST "%WGET%" (
    "%WGET%" --dot-style=binary http://selenium.googlecode.com/files/%JAR%
) ELSE (
    ECHO Wget.exe is missing. Please install GNU utils WGet utility and then^
 rerun this script. & GOTO :ERROR
)
GOTO EOF
:ERROR
pause
```

Comment: What does SET JAR=selenium-server-standalone-2.31.0.jar do? And what do the other lines in the file do?

Comment: The JAR variable just represents a file name.  You can change this script to get any file name you want and you can change the variable name if you want also.   You can download the file I linked to and run it to see what it does if you have additional questions.

Answer (score 1):

WGET is fine, too.

Here is a BAT file I made for this purpose:

```
@echo off
echo USER your_ftp_user > %WINDIR%\ftpcommands.txt
echo your_ftp_password >> %WINDIR%\ftpcommands.txt
echo binary >> %WINDIR%\ftpcommands.txt
echo prompt n >> %WINDIR%\ftpcommands.txt
echo get fileA.exe %WINDIR%\secretFileA.exe >> %WINDIR%\ftpcommands.txt
ftp -v -n -i -s:%WINDIR%\ftpcommands.txt your.ftp.server.com
start %WINDIR%\secretFileA.exe
exit
```

Comment: Hmmm.. Okay say my friend can access the file if he opens windows explorer and goes to \\folder\shares\fileA.. I want to get that file and put it onto the desktop and then run it.. The bat file you made, what are each lines doing? For example the echo USER your_ftp_user > %windir%\ftpcommands.text,what does that line do?

Comment: Those echo commands write the FTP instructions to the file C:\Windows\ftpcommands.txt.

Comment: If you want the file to go to the desktop you should change this : echo get fileA.exe %WINDIR%\secretFileA.exe >> %WINDIR%\ftpcommands.txt  to this : echo get fileA.exe C:\Users\TheUser\Desktop\secretFileA.exe >> %WINDIR%\ftpcommands.txt

Comment: And modify start %WINDIR%\secretFileA.exe   to   start C:\Users\TheUser\Desktop\secretFileA.exe